# Doubts about Json web token and users' sessions control

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, frontend, backend

Well, i just took a basic Backend development course with Nodejs and it could be said that i'm newby in the web development world. In one of the modules of the course i learned how to secure my backend's routes with Json web tokens and now i'm starting to develop a basic chat using reactjs for the frontend side and Nodejs to develop my backend. But now that i'm thinking about the security of the page, there are many questions that comes to my mind that weren´t explained in the course. I've planned to validate an user to access to the page routes with a login sending a JWT. So considering that fact the following are my questions:

1. How to get the token from the frontend?

The course i took was completly focused on the backend, so i worked with postman sending the requests and storing the data from the reponses in the enviroment variables. So i don't know how to get the token from the frontend (i don't know if i can get it from any side of the cache storage or i need to save it in a database or something).

2. How to revoke the token?

Well, i know that i can specify an expiration time for the token, but in this case i don't want that expires unless the user logs out from the page. I've read from some sites that it's not posible to delete it that easy but they recommend to remove the token from the client side and for the server side, saving the token in a forbidden list which contains tokens that are not reached their expiration time but they are not longer available.

3. The last one is, how to refresh the jwt?

Well, i don't know if the question was formulated correctly but here is it and i think is related with the second one. Imagine that i don't want the token lasts forever, instead i want the token expires in one week in case the user doesn't enter in the entire week, but once the user enters, the time expiration refreshes. In short words, i want the user can stay logged unless he doesn't enter to the page in one week. What would be the most pratical to do?

Without anymore to say, thanks for reading and i would appreciate any tip or code example that you have to resolve my questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the token from the frontend?
The token should be sent as the part of REST API, `header`. There are many ways to send token but most apt is to set an Authorization Bearer Header.

More on Authorization [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

e.g.:

```
  headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken)
```

In NodeJS if you are using express you can write middleware to retrieve the token:

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, "your_token_secret");
        next();
      } catch (error) {
          res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Invalid Token'
          });
      }
    };
```

How to revoke the token?

In your frontend application store the token in `localStorage` for the desired amount of time, and on load of application check for the localStorage token if it's there and not expired authorize else ask for login again which will generate a new token all together something like:

```
        onAppLoad() {
             saveAuthData(token_from_backend, date_from_backend);
        }
    
    saveAuthData(token: string, expirationDate: Date) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('expiration', expirationDate.toISOString());
      }
    
        clearAuthData() {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem('expiration');
        }
    
        getAuthData() {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const expiration = localStorage.getItem('expiration');
            if (!token || !expiration) {
              return;
            }
            return {
              token: token,
              expirationDate: new Date(expiration)
            };
          }
```

You can also auto-login user without asking for login credentials if the token is valid

```
    autoAuthUser() {
          const authInformation = getAuthData();
          const now = new Date();
          const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
          if (expiresIn > 0) {
            token = authInformation.token;
            isAuthenticated = true;
            setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
           
          }
      }
```

Setting the timer to revoke a token, for this mush time the token should be present in localStorage after that delete it or replace it with the refreshed token

```
setAuthTimer(duration: number) {
   tokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.logout();
    }, duration * 1000);
  }
```

Comment: how about storing the token inside an httpOnly cookie and set the expire date of an cookie same like the token? the cookie would erase automaticall when the token expire

Comment: Yeah sure, but we should try to make server stateless if we are not building something like an online cart where we need to track user orders we should avoid cookies to avoid cookie stealing, xss vulnerability etc.

Comment: @Navitas28 Thank you, this is what i was looking for.